# Cant Select an item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

My goal was to have a ListBox that changed its template according to the data
Now I did this with ItemTemplateSelector and the templates were selected correctly but my problem is that I can not select an item
In even handlaer, Selection_Changed, or in Mouse_Double_Click, or whatever, the selectedindex is always zero.
And selectedItem is always equal to our first row

Can you suggest a solution so I can choose the item?

```
<ListBox   x:Name="listBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource studentDataTemplateSelector}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="listBox_MouseDoubleClick">
</ListBox>
```

```
 <local:StudentDataTemplateSelector x:Key="studentDataTemplateSelector"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="templateMusic">
            <ccontrols:FileUi  ContainStr="1Item" TitleStr="{Binding NameFile}" SizeStr="{Binding Size}" CreatedTime="{Binding CreateTime}" ImageUri="Assets/Music.png"/>


        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="templateMovie">
            <ccontrols:FileUi ContainStr="1Item" TitleStr="{Binding NameFile}" SizeStr="{Binding Size}" CreatedTime="{Binding CreateTime}" ImageUri="Assets/video.png"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

```
 public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (item==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (item.GetType() == typeof(File))
            {
                if (Enum.TryParse((((File)item).Extension), true, out ExtensionClass.Music sample))
                {
                    return
                         element.FindResource("templateMusic")
                         as DataTemplate;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return
                        element.FindResource("templateMovie")
                        as DataTemplate;
                }

             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe conflict with `ItemContainerStyle` is there `Template` defined?

Comment: @aepot  I removed it but  not changed

Comment: It's better to add to the question some reproducible example then.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do and more important, what exactly is actually  happening. When you click on an item, then the `ListBox.SelectedItem` will change to this item. This will trigger the `SelectionChanged` event. To set the selected item programmatically, simply set `ListBox.SelectedItem` to a value of the `ListBox.Items` collection or the binding source of the `ItemsSource` property. The `SelectedItem` must be the exact instance that the `ItemsControl` contains.

Comment: It is recommended to bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` to a property of your view model (or what ever your data source is) and modify it via this data binding. If youneed more help please provide more details.